# Jquery .then function after get result not working inside the foreach loop

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery function which calls the api service.I have written it inside a each loop.Every time it reaches the `promiseGet.then(function (result)` line, goes again top and access the next iteration. After complete all the loops only,it gives me the result but which is not expected order of execution as like in the array declared.My aim is to execute the push statement after every iteration completes. I don't know where I'm making mistake in it. Here I have tried so far.

```
$scope.GetNavigationMenu = function NavigationMenu() {
        var modules = ["Dashboard", "Requirements", "Deviation Report", "Schedule", "Permission"];
        var list = [];
        $.each(modules, function (x, i) {
            var data = { Module: i };
            var promiseGet = httpService.get(serviceBase + rightsPermissionUrl, data);
            promiseGet.then(function (result) {
                list.push(result.data);
            }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
            });
        });
        $scope.navigationMenu = list;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want an array such that the value at each index of the array corresponds to the item gotten from that index in `modules`, you should use `Promise.all` instead. Map each module to a Promise, and then call `Promise.all` on the array of Promises, and then the value it resolves to will be your `list` in the proper order:

```
$scope.GetNavigationMenu = function NavigationMenu() {
  var modules = ["Dashboard", "Requirements", "Deviation Report", "Schedule", "Permission"];
  Promise.all(modules.map(Module => httpService.get(serviceBase + rightsPermissionUrl, { Module })))
    .then((list) => {
      // do stuff with `list` array
      $scope.navigationMenu = list;
    })
   .catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```